# Nslookup function within script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to create a script which can perform a DNS lookup for a web address.

This is the start of my script

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "enter web address : "
read address 
echo "Entered web address : $address"
```

I know you need to add a `nslookup` function into this script but I don't how to implement it. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have the address you want to look up in a shell variable `$address`, just call `nslookup` with that variable as argument at the end of your script:

```
nslookup "$address"
```

No magic here.