# How does Command substitution, dig and +short work within this script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, dns

Could someone please explain how `dig` and `+short` work within this script and why they are used? Also could someone explain how the command substitution works within the code as I am struggling to understand how command substitution works.

## Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter web address : "
read address
echo "Entered web address : $address"
nslookup "$address"
ping -c 4 $(dig +short "$address" | head -1)
```

### Script in Use:

```
Enter web address : 
gutenberg.org

Entered web address : gutenberg.org
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   gutenberg.org
Address: 152.19.134.47

PING 152.19.134.47 (152.19.134.47) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 152.19.134.47: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=118 ms
64 bytes from 152.19.134.47: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=165 ms
64 bytes from 152.19.134.47: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=116 ms
64 bytes from 152.19.134.47: icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=111 ms

--- 152.19.134.47 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 111.326/127.824/165.079/21.675 ms
enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: It is impressive that someone used `nslookup` and `dig` in the same file and they didn't get struck by lightning.

Comment: @chicks [here ...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107799/how-would-i-ping-ip-address-produced-from-script)

Comment: @Ravexina It was [not just you](https://askubuntu.com/q/1092206/371118)

Answer (score 1):

So we take this line from the script:

```
ping -c 4 $(dig +short "$address" | head -1)
```

The shell will break it up for white space, substitute the variable and then see that it needs to run the command inside the `$()` first.  So it has to run this first:

```
dig +short "$address" | head -1
```

The double quotes around `$address` aren't strictly necessary, but they're a good habit to get into in case your data ends up with spaces in it the shell won't split it up for you.

So if I do this with `$address="yahoo.com"`....

```
$ dig +short yahoo.com | head -1
72.30.35.10
```

With the `72.30.35.10` as the output of the pipeline inside of the command substitution the line from the top becomes

```
ping -c 4 72.30.35.10
```

which pings the IP only 4 times before quitting as you've experienced when trying it.  Otherwise `ping` would run until you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

`ping -c 4` : 4 steps

`head -1 :` shows only first line of output

dig +short shows only "A" Record

```
mirek@Mirek-nuc:~$ dig yahoo.com +short
72.30.35.9
98.137.246.7
72.30.35.10
98.138.219.231
98.138.219.232
98.137.246.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also needs some help understanding how the command substitution works. Thanks

Comment: IMO the answer is incomplete, here missing an explanation like as: *So the output of `dig +short yahoo.com | head -1` will be `72.30.35.9`, that string will be placed in the place of the command substitution and in this way we will construct the command `ping -c 4 72.30.35.9`.*

Comment: I wrote another answer on this Q to try to clarify the command substitution part of this.